# How are threads created concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading

Here we have 2 thread class objects t1 and t2.

```
main()
{
 //object creation
 t1.start();
 t2.start();
 }
```

this logically means that first line 1 will execute and finish and hence the thread and then the line 2 will execute. Then could anyone explain how java creates two different threads and at the same time.

Comment: You will have to elaborate on that question. Right now it's very unclear.

Comment: This your phrase is unclear: "line 1 will execute and finish and hence the thread" - if you think that the thread ends after first line being executed - this is wrong. After t1.start() the new thread will be created, as after t2.start()

Comment: I mean to say that if statements are executed sequentially by JVM then as it seems t1.start() will execute first and finish. After that only t2.start() will be called, but that does not go with the definition of multi threading. I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 4):

**that first line 1 will execute and finish...:** This is true.

**... and hence the thread**: Not true

Your conclusion is incorrect. The call `t1.start()` is just a normal function call with respect to the current thread executing main. `t1.start()` will be executed and hence the current thread will wait for the call to finish.

But, `t1.start();` creates a new Thread and returns. Now this thread is independent of the current thread executing main, and can execute at any time in the future. Also, the current thread doesn't wait for the created thread to finish executing. This explains why your conclusion is false.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. "But, t1.start(); creates a new Thread and returns." this statement clears my doubt actually. If calling start method just "spawns a new thread and returns" then things fall to logic but else I assume that only once t1.start() completes, JVM will execute t2.start() and in that case it does not seem to be multi threading.

Answer (score 0):

`t1.start()` will launch a new thread that will be executed in parallel (not blocking main) so `t2.start()` will launch another thread in parallel either t1's thread has finished or not.

This way at the end you'll have three threads running in parallel (t1, t2 and the main thread).